# Why doesn't TypeScript complain about an incorrect return type?

Tags: typescript

Please consider this example:

```js
// all properties in Item should be optional, this is by design
type Item = {
    id?: number
    name?: string
}

interface WithVersion {
    version: number
}

export type ResultType =
    & WithVersion // #1 try to remove it
    & {
        version: number
        list: Item[];
    };


export interface Data {
    list: Array<string>;
}

// As per my understanding, this function should not compile, because elem.list is not assignable to list in ResultType
const builder = <T extends Data>(data: Array<T>): ResultType[] => {
    const result = data.map((elem) => ({
        list: elem.list, // #2 list is string[], whereas ResultType expects list to be Item[]
        version: 2,
    }))
    return result // #3
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQVtQJYBMB+ALigDsBXBAIwgCcscyBDBCEqAZ2DtzIHMMAXwwY+8OgDNmAY2gB1XMAAWANXqdcAezLpG2AG4btZUpRr1hoiAA8wWusCihIUAEoROFADbAAKuDQyPpQAGRQiirqdJo6UAD08VAAxACMznQgzlpQdIhaRnjAIeGYOOVQRjEmZlS0DBU43rjcpHCIANoAugDcIUJ91nYOTuL00nJQACLMwMx65c2tUACCdHTMIAA83LwCAHx9IhgyOtxQ1BS43vj0KFBbflC28GT4nNOzzPsAFPhfpDWG22fn2AEpSB4vL4ApBuih9gscKcyOc8tCnKh-nMAHQIZhgH4-CDeRBghFQH5lRpQJbAUgkxA4ukAGgSSWSACZaS1Rh9dnx+N02QB3ZT0CDMD5Qnz+QLPOwQGTAD507IXaDtBDdELlKqxUxQTks-pgsEhPLACh0XTo2XslIAZmEQA)

I am a bit confused by the assignability rules of TypeScript.

Try to remove `WithVersion` from `ResultType`. TypeScript will complain about the assignability of `result` to return type of `builder` function (`ResultType`).

Further more, if you define explicit return type for `Array.prototype.map` callback, TypeScript will complain just as I expect:

```js
const builder = <T extends Data>(data: Array<T>): ResultType[] => {
    const result = data.map((elem):ResultType => ({
        list: elem.list, // error as expected
        version: 2,
    }))
    return result
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why there is no error without explicit type for `map` callback. It is clear that `string[]` is not assignable to `Item[]`.

   ```js
   declare let foo: string[]
   declare let bar: Item[]

   foo = bar
   bar = foo
   ```
2. Why does an error appear when I remove `WithVersion` from the `ResultType` definition? It looks like that intersection of `WithVersion` and `{ version: number list: Item[]; }` somehow affects `ResultType`, whereas in my opinion, this intersection should not affect it at all.

**SIMPLIFIED VERSION**

```js
type Item = {
    id?: number
    name?: string
}

interface WithVersion {
    version: number
}

export type ResultType =
    & WithVersion // #1 try to remove it
    & {
        version: number
        list: Item[];
    };

declare let result: ResultType;
declare let list: string[];
let a = {
    list,
    version: 2,
};
result = a;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYZ2vw)

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50608) in TS repo

Comment: That is ... weird. It's hard to see how it isn't a bug, but...

Comment: Putting it in the TS playground, I found it shows the error you marked as #2 when you remove the WithVersion from the ResultType type definition. I'm uncertain why it does not display it when WithVersion is set, though

Comment: @DubiousMaster - RIght, that's the point of the question. He says *"Try to remove `WithVersion` from `ResultType`. TypeScript will complain about the assignability of result to return type of builder function (`ResultType`)."*

Comment: Really strange... but if one of `Item`'s properties is *not* optional, the check seems to work.

Comment: @majusebetter yes, but the point is - it should be optional

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Still, that's a useful piece of info.

Comment: FWIW, here's a repro with no generic function, no call to `map`, etc. Literally just assigning to a `ResultType[]` variable: https://tsplay.dev/WGRGkm Has the same behavior -- no error if the `& WithVersion` is in `ResultType`, error as expected if it doesn't, error as expected if any of `Item`'s properties is non-optional. This really smells like a bug to me.

Comment: It looks like, that this intersection `& WithVersion` some how affects the type, but I can't understand why

Comment: I was able to simplify the repro a bit further: https://tsplay.dev/wglG6N

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine: actually, while intersecting with `{ version: number }` works, interestingly intersecting with `{ list: Item[] }` seems to work, too.

Comment: Also, intersecting with `{ version: number,  list: Item[] }` works too.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - Oh wow, good catch -- literally just [intersecting it with itself](https://tsplay.dev/Nng5am) changes the behavior. V. weird indeed.

Comment: Yep, made a [playground for this](https://tsplay.dev/WkKz0W)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine: yet another [shorter version](https://tsplay.dev/WvAzAm). Looks like adding the very same type to the intersection blinds the compiler.

Comment: Heaven help us, it's also influenced by whether you use a type alias or inline type definition (and here I thought type aliases were, you know, *aliases*): https://tsplay.dev/WyX26m

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you last example drives me crazy :D

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Yeah. :-D

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine: combining all this together sounds like a good candidate for a bug report. Please consider this and edit your question with a link (if you decide to open a bug) so that we can all track this for further reference. I bookmarked this question to come back here once for a while as this bugs me too.

Comment: @WiktorZychla sure thing. Will create a bug today and provide a link to the question.

Comment: Presumably this is some quirk of how [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) works, as described in [ms/TS#16047](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16047).  Personally I consider weak type detection to be like excess property detection in that it is not a true type safety issue so much as a linter warning, so I don't know that it *really* matters how it works with nonweak intersections of weak properties.  I could write this up as an answer but I don't know if we're waiting on ms/TS#50608 first?

Comment: @jcalz please write up an answer,  I'd willing to bet that it is strictly related to Weak type detection.  Since you are not 100% sure I will wait for official comment on github and then accept your answer. Think, it will be fair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR [Weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) doesn't always occur for [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types); this seems to be behaving as designed, although the particular behavior you're seeing might be a design limitation (update: The issue is marked as a bug in [microsoft/TypeScript#50608](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50608) but it's on the backlog so it's probably not going to be changed anytime soon.)

---

From a purely [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) standpoint, `string` is indeed assignable to `Item`.  The `Item` type has [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) `id` and `name`, and values of type `string` are missing these properties, so there's no apparent conflict.  Reading `"foo".id` or `"bar".name` gives you `undefined` in both cases.  If TypeScript only cared about structural compatibility, then none of your examples would have compiler errors.

Of course, it is probably a mistake to assign a `string` value to something that expects an `Item`.  TypeScript has several features to try to catch these sort of non-type-safety mistakes.  These are more like linter warnings than type errors.

One such feature is [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection).  A *weak type* is an object type whose properties are all optional, like `Item`.  Weak type detection causes the compiler to complain if you try to assign something to a weak type if there is no overlap in properties.  (Aside: a more well-known such feature is [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), in which object literals are not allowed to have unexpected properties.)  Weak type detection is why you will get a warning if you assign a `string` to an `Item` or a `string[]` to an `Item[]` or an `{x: string; y: string}` to an `{x: Item; y: string}`:

```
const foo = { x: "", y: "" }
const bar: { x: Item; y: string } = foo; // error
```

---

So then: why don't you get a warning when you try to assign an `{x: string, y: string}` to an `{x: Item} & {y: string}`?

```
const baz: { x: Item } & { y: string } = foo; // no error?!
```

Why is there a difference with [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)?

Well, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#16047](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16047), the pull request that implemented weak type detection,  weak type detection does not occur in intersection types unless *all* the intersected types are weak types.  Since `{y: string}` is not a weak type (and technically neither is `{x: Item}` because the `x` property is not optional), then the intersection does not undergo weak type checking at all.  Therefore things fall back to the normal structural type check, and the assignment succeeds.

This still raises the question of *why* weak type detection was implemented so that intersections are usually exempt.  I don't really see this explicitly documented, but it looks like there was a prior version of this feature implemented at [microsoft/TypeScript#3842](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3842) where weak type detection for intersections caused undesirable behavior.  My presumption here is that the intent was to be somewhat conservative and only emit errors in cases known to be bad, and there are some intersection situations we want to accept (maybe generics?).

---

In any case, this is definitely behaving as designed, although the particular consequences here is apparently considered a bug, according to  [microsoft/TypeScript#50608](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50608).  It's been relegated to the backlog, so it's probably not going to be changed anytime soon.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQVtQJYBMB+ALigDsBXBAIwgCcscyBDBCEqAZ2DtzIHMMAXwwYAxgHsy3KADMJElOigAPUgCJ1AGiggN6qCMnTgUaszqk0q0nEQBuXaW68BhpfImOA9N6j06CQZjGXMALysbWHgkISgAMmU9Lh4+fndUTx8-CQBrZhAMIA)

Comment: It looks like it was a bug