# Should all body parameters of any endpoint be declared as optional types?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nodejs-server

When I send body data to an endpoint on my Node/Express server, there is **no guarantee that the request actually contains all the required fields**. Is it, therefore, correct to always declare all body properties as optional types in TypeScript like I did in below example?

```
interface SignUpBody {
    username?: string, // all these properties are declared as optional (? operator)
    email?: string,
    password?: string,
}

export const signup: RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, SignUpBody, unknown> = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const username = req.body.username;
        const email = req.body.email?.toLowerCase();
        const passwordRaw = req.body.password;

        if (!username || !email || !passwordRaw) { // optional types force me to check them first
            throw createHttpError(400, 'Parameters missing');
        }

[...]
}
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73580368/why-doesnt-typescript-complain-about-an-incorrect-return-type) answer. Currently there is a bug in TS if you use intersection with `weak types`